# Is it possible to use python tornado framework with phonegap?

Tags: python, tornado, phonegap

I'm developing an multi-page web application using python tornado framework (includes API), and because the application is said to be used in mobile I decided to use phonegap to test on mobile.

Now the question, Is it possible to make tornado application listen to the phonegap (from mobile) ?

Comment: Tornado is a server side technology. It runs in your server. Of course, it's possible to use Tornado with any frontend technology including Phonegap, as long as you're using a protocol supported by Tornado, for example HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you have idea if it still possible if the tornado is used also as a client side to show data in app by jijna2?

Comment: Jinja2 is also server-side technology. It renders the templates **on the server** before sending to the client.

Comment: I think the issue is the order of files and paths, for example, in phonegap I have to set the index.html (the first page) file in www folder that phonegap created for me, in the other hand in tornado all html files have to be in somepath/templates.

Answer (score 1):

basically you want to install Tornado app in some/local server server, and create API calls from Phonegap -> Tornado server ?

It's possible, if you're developing locally - you have a local address that you define ( 127.0.0.1:8080 or whatever )

Then from phonegap you can generate Ajax calls towards your server.

The best approach in such case, is to not use Tornado with HTML files, with API work always with JSON outputs ....